# Why does "up" mean "into pieces" in "tear up"?

Tags: meaning

I looked up the Oxford dictionary, it says that *up* could mean "into pieces/apart". I want to know why. What do you native speakers feel when you say *up* in "tear up" or "rip up"?

There is an example sentence in Oxford dictionary:

> They've had the road up to lay some pipes.

As far as I could understand, *up* means upward. How could it mean "into pieces"? I don't understand.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does one top up or top off rechargeable batteries?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87632/does-one-top-up-or-top-off-rechargeable-batteries) (John Lawler's answer addresses 'completive _up_').

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, crucial to the accepted answer on the other page is that there is some similarity between recharging batteries and 'filling containers with liquids'. There us no such similarity here.

Comment: It is like a separable prefix in German. It is really just part of the verb and doesn't have to make sense. Except in English it's a suffix and we put a space in between.

Comment: Note that there is the image of tearing a piece of paper into bits and throwing them up in the air.

Comment: @jsw29 You're saying that completive up sometimes doesn't relate to the filling, repletion metaphor? (You are.)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, yes, or more precisely I am pointing out that in some cases (e.g. *top up the battery*) it is fairly easy to see how the completive *up* is related to the primary sense of *up* (to a higher position), while in others (e.g. *tear up the paper*) it is not. Because this question is about a case of the latter kind, it is not a duplicate of the one about recharging batteries. It is reasonable for the OP to wonder why we say *tear up* rather than *tear down*, while an analogous question does not arise in the battery case.

Comment: *break up*, *break down*...

Comment: @jsw29 And J Lawler describes this broadening: '...  phrasal verbs. One uses the common completive up particle (burn up 'burn completely', fix up 'fix completely').' ... 'Does this answer your question?' _How can the answer on a site devoted to linguists be 'No'?_

Comment: I am reminded of an old cartoon in which the cartoonist imagined a paper towel dispenser in a washroom with the instructions "pull down, tear up" -- intending that one should pull the end of the paper downward out of the dispenser, then pull upward to tear off a piece of paper. This results in a hilarious misunderstanding. https://www.madmagazine.com/blog/2014/04/18/don-martin-alone-in-a-washroom-for-the-first-time

Comment: @jsw29 Well put. I might add that we while we *tear up* a street, we *tear down* a building. So it is indeed a **very** good question why the first usage applies to the destruction of a piece of paper and the second does not.

Answer (score 26):

The *up* particle in the verb *tear up* doesn't mean 'into pieces'; that's what it means with *tear*, because of what *tear* means. Note that, because English orthography, there are two verbs *tear*, pronounced differently, one transitive, one intransitive, with completely unrelated meanings. And both of them have phrasal verbs with *up*. The same *up*.

- *I want them to tear up the agreement.* **/tɛr əp/** 'rip into pieces' (transitive)
- *I want them to tear up at the climax*. **/tɪr əp/** 'start to cry' (intransitive)

**This** particle *up* -- there are others, like the *up*'s in *look up, throw up,* or *stand up* -- appears with many phrasal verbs in a completive sense. It's one way to extend the sense of a verb. Phrasal verbs with this particle, like *burn up, drink up, eat up, use up, read up, write up,* and *finish up,* all refer to some event or activity going to completion, whatever 'completion' is in each particular case.

So if you're ripping something up, it ends up in shreds. But if your eyes are filling up with tears, you feel like crying. Both of these could be spelled  as *tearing up*. Same *up*, different *tear*; but no shreds involved with crying.

Something that *burns up* burns completely; a house that *burns down* burns to the ground. Consequently *the house burned up* means *the house burned down,* a fact which has not escaped the attention of most six-year-old English speakers.

There are literally thousands of English phrasal verbs with *up* (because there are many thousands of English verbs, and most of them have several phrasal verbs). Many have the completive sense of *up*.

When you're thinking of a verb, think about its phrasal verbs, to see what it can mean in context. Like the variegated prepositions and complements that verbs take, the particles they form phrasal verbs with are part of the meaning of a verb. Each one is a puzzle piece, which fits some, and not other, contexts.

Comment: When I encounter the second sense I usually misread it as the first, because that sense of _tear up_ is not in my active vocabulary - probably because I have it marked as "foreign" in my mind.

Comment: Yes, there is a completive sense of *up*, but in some cases one can see a connection between that sense and an upward movement, either literal or metaphorical, while in others the connection is far from obvious. *Tear up the agreement* is an example of the latter kind. What the OP seems to be curious about is **why** we say *tear up the agreement*, when nothing even resembling an upward movement is involved. I suspect that the origins of that use of *up* are in the past that is far too distant for any explanation of it to be possible, but if so, then **that** is the answer to the question.

Comment: _Why_ questions about linguistics, especially about metaphors, just don't have answers. If they did, they would all start with "For some speakers, in some areal/social speech group, in some contexts, ...". Because everybody makes up their own grammar, and their own reasons for every part of it. Who knows better, after all? And they they're stuck with that.

Comment: Aren't *why* questions what etymology is about?

Comment: No. Etymology is about who and how, but why is a matter for individual speakers, and there were millions of them.

Comment: @JohnLawler would you be so kind to read this: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/559045/387044?

Comment: @ jsw29 *"why we say tear up the agreement, when nothing even resembling an upward movement is involved"*  To be devil's advocate, or just plain annoying: If a written agreement is held down flat on a surface with one hand and torn with the other, it is almost inevitable the tearing hand moves upwards.

Comment: *"burn up, drink up, eat up, use up, read up, write up, and finish up ... refer to ...completion"* I don't think "read up" qualifies as an indicator of completion. If I read up on the French Revolution for an exam, I'm unlikely to complete the subject.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica, yes, that would be a very satisfactory explanation, if only we had some reason to think that this upward movement is what led people to start using *up* in this way. I know that your 'explanation' is not meant seriously, but it s a good illustration of the **kind** of answer one is hoping for when asks these why-questions. Of course, it is often the case that no such explanation can be found, but then it should be said clearly that no explanation can be found.

Comment: If you want to know why _up_ is used, that's a different question and involves metaphor instead of syntax.

Comment: @JohnLawler, the OP did not say that the question involves syntax. The question was 'as far as i could understand,up means upward,how could it mean "into piece"'; while somewhat inelegantly formulated, this is seems to be a question about the connection between this meaning of *up* and its primary meaning.

Comment: *"So if you're ripping something up, it ends **up** in shreds."* I see what you did there...

Answer (score 13):

"Up" in this case is an adverb that gives the preceding verb a sense of finality. As in done. Finished. Completed.

Eat up: finish eating.

Shut up: keep completely silent starting right now.

Wake up: stop sleeping and be completely awake.

Look at the definition No. 16:

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/up?s=t

Comment: "Eat up" doesn't really mean finish eating.  Depending on context, it could mean either to start eating, or to finish eating all of something.  E.g. "Dinner's on the table, eat up!" or "These leftovers really need eating up before they spoil".

Comment: I wouldn't call "up" in any of these examples "a sense of finality"

Comment: They told Little Jimmy not to go into the garden at night. But he did, and the tiger *ate him all up*.

Comment: Definition 17 seems more relevant.

Comment: The 1st para seems correct, but not the examples. "Tear the paper" means 1 rip. "Tear up the paper" means destruction by rips. Whereas "Wake up!" isn't a more extreme version of "Wake!"

Comment: @jamesqf There's definitely some scope for opinion and usage variation here, but to me "eat up" would definitely imply "eat it all". In the case of "Dinner's on the table, eat up!" I would take the message as not just "start eating" but "don't hold back, eat until you're full".

Answer (score 11):

[Merriam Webster's definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tear%20up) of "tear up" is:

> to damage, remove, or effect an opening in

with the example

> tore up the street to lay a new water main

MW also says that "tear up" with this meaning is first recorded from 1620 so the usage is quite old.

Also the [Oxford Advanced Learners' dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/tear-up#:%7E:text=tear%20somethingup&text=to%20destroy%20a%20document%2C%20etc,letters%20he%20had%20sent%20her.) defines "tear up" as a *phrasal verb* with a very similar meaning.

This does not mean that "up" can mean "into pieces" in any sense, it only means that the "tear" and "up" used together can mean "to rip into small pieces".

As Ricky's answer says the word "up" is used to give the verb a sense of completeness.

There are a number of these phrasal verbs with "up" used in this way, they include: "crumple up" (meaning to crush) "bundle up" (meaning, in British use at least, to tie up into a bundle), and "zip up" (meaning to close an item of clothing or a bag using a zip fastener). In each case there is a sense of completeness and finality.

I suspect, but have no proof for my suspicion, that the origin of this usage lies in the fact that the items which are being torn, crumpled and bundled (zip fasteners are much later than the 17C) are actually raised from their resting places in order for the action to be taken. This is particularly true of items which are "bundled up" as the resulting bundle sits much higher than the individual items before they are brought together.

In the case of "having the road up" the road surface and part of the substructure is physically raised when the operation is carried out so there is no mystery there. The same is true of "digging up a bush" or "digging up buried treasure". Having said that the sense of completeness is also present.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I was a poor English student, but I have been a native US English speaker for 63 years.

> What do you native speakers feel when you say "up" in "tear up" or "rip up"?

When you tear something, you have to start somewhere right? Tear up or rip up, is from the bottom up, probably to do, originally, with ensuring that you tear through whatever signature may be at the bottom of a contract, for instance. I've always suspected the origins to do with medieval contract law. The bottom of the sheet is usually closest to you on the desk, and that is where the signatures are. Any sense of finality may also derive from that.

Tear down is from the top down and is commonly used where you have a complex assembly where it would be difficult or impossible to disassemble from the bottom up, but where you might be referring to "ripping through something", not used a lot in reference to paper, but tearing down a snow covered mountain has everything to do with tearing down, ripping and carving through the snow.

Time is up, likely derives from the desk candles, with hour marks on them, used to work after sunset, prior to electricity (I used them in my forts when camping out as a child). You were out of time when the flame converted your candle to the smoke that invariable rose up out of the flame. The same was true of oil lamps, but I am not aware of any that had time marks on them.

Normally we sleep near the horizontal plane, so waking up, involves sitting or standing up. Here there's also a weak association with finality/time, as sleep time ends when you are up.

---

So today, which-ever direction in which you physically tear any paper, there's finality to it in the sense that you are done with that. You have ripped it up. It doesn't make sense to tear or rip it down, because we use those phrases to describe a more complex process that has less finality to it. When you tear-down an engine, you can always put it back together again (with or without a few extra parts laying around when you're done).

Comment: Is there any evidence that people more frequently tear up sheets of paper from the bottom up, rather than from the top down, or sideways? Also, to tear up a sheet of paper (i.e. turn into small shreds) one normally needs to make a number of ripping movements, in different directions.

Comment: @jsw29, I am not aware of any studies having been done on the matter. Your point regarding multiple tears would result in an increase of the number of bits of paper! LOL. Anyway, no matter which way you tear it, you can't tear it down, because that is commonly reserved for another use.

Comment: You might say tear it asunder, but you'd never actually say tear it left or tear it right.

Comment: Tearing down a building is usually an irreversible process, and quite final.

Comment: Oh yes, that is true. I suppose I should have said usually has less finality to it. My neighbors house caught fire a few years back and had to be torn down, but then they put it back up again, almost exactly like the original ;).

Comment: @jwdonahue, 'no matter which way you tear it, you can't tear it down, because that is commonly reserved for another use' would be a very different answer from the one you actually posted, and it would immediately lead to the question of why the meanings of *tear down* and *tear up* are separated in this way. And if there is no evidence about whether people more often perform the act from the bottom up or from the top down, then your answer will simply not be convincing to those actually do tear the paper from the top down.